# Running a korPus text-mining function across multiple text files in R

Tags: r, for-loop, tokenize, lapply, pos-tagger

I would like to run two R functions from the library `korPus` on a bunch of `txt` files. First, I want to `tokenize` or `treetag` these texts and then to run `MTLD` on the outputs and save results in a single document. I'm trying to do this using `lapply` or `for loop`. The basic syntax for both commands is straightforward:

```
tokenized_1 <- tokenize("txt", lang="en")
MLTD(tokenized_1)
```

I've tried the following

```
files <- list.files(path="path/to/dir", pattern="*.txt", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
tokenized<-(lapply(files, tokenize, lang='en'))
```

But, this merges all results into a one file whereas I'd like to go through all files separately. In addition, it creates an invalid class for `MTLD` function.

I am familiar with `for loop` from `shell scripting` and I thought this would do what I want but

```
for (i in files){tokenize(i, lang='en')}
```

does nothing. I'm aware that this is a very naive and simplistic approach but I'm not a very experienced `R` user.

Comment: What do you mean, "merges all results into one file?" Your `lapply` should create a list, whose components are the results of tokenising each file in isolation.

Comment: A wrong word choice. You're right, it does not really 'merge' them but creates a list with all outputs. However, `MTLD` cannot read them in this format. I guess I'd have to split them.

Comment: Just use `lapply` again: `lapply(tokenized, MLTD)`.

Comment: Ha, I didn't know it's that simple. Thanks! My results look like this and they are on separate lines `Total number of tokens: 6257
Total number of types:  1050

Measure of Textual Lexical Diversity
                MTLD: 53.53
   Number of factors: 116.89
         Factor size: 0.72
    SD tokens/factor: 25.88 (all factors)
                      25.78 (complete factors only)` Do you have a suggestion how to say grep only lines containing `MTLD:` ?

Comment: I've solved this second problem as well. This is what I used and it worked: `sapply(lapply(results,slot,'MTLD'),'[',c('MTLD'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply`

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.txt")
text.tagged <- lapply(filenames, function(x) treetag(x, treetagger="manual", lang="en",
                                                     TT.options=list(path=filepath, preset="en")))

text.tagged[1]
```